# Prevent scroll to top when using "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" on iOS 10

Tags: css, objective-c, ios10, hybrid-mobile-app, ios10.2

I am working on an iOS 10 app where there is a webkit page containing a vertical scrollable area with CSS rule `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

If I scroll down the area and tap to the clock on the iPad status bar, the area is scrolled to the top.

How can I disable this "scroll to the top" behavior maintaining the smooth scrolling given by `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`?

Both an Objective-C or JavaScript solution is accepted.

Thank you